# MySQL Workbench Closes Unexpectedly

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm using CentOS 6.4, and did

```
sudo yum install mysql-workbench-community.x86_64
```

That installed MySQL workbench version 6.1

When I launch the application it lists MySQL Connections, and has a box for Local instance 3306.

When I double click that box the app just closes.  WTH?

---

edit: it's printing this on the console

> /usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbscintilla.so: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_get_realized

Comment: Try launching it from a terminal emulator and see if any error message get printed.

Comment: I think it's a feature, not a bug ;) ...I get unexpected closes several times a day using it, and for the strangest reasons. Eventually you learn to click things in just the right order and it sorta works :)

Answer (score 4):

If you've got the same issue like me with Workbench unexpectedly crashing it's easy to resolve:

Edit -> Preferences -> tab "general" and check "Force use of software based rendering for EER diagrams"

At least it's worth a try!

Answer (score 1):

I too was experiencing same problem (on CentOS 6.4). I followed what they concluded on [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70332) bug report file. I installed the Workbench 6.0.9 release and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the same issue like me with Workbench unexpectedly crashing while opening previous session with tables then just clean up **sql_workspaces** folder with their sub-directories:

```
rm -rf ~/.mysql/workbench/sql_workspaces/*
```

Unfortunately I have the repetition of this event every time so I created the alias in my ~/.bashrc (pro-)file:

```
alias fix_workbench='rm -rf /home/user/.mysql/workbench/sql_workspaces/*'
```

P.S.: My MySQL Workbench's version is: 8.0.12. The debug log is too long, including Register/Memory dumps and Backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

As plan B you can also use dbeaver. It works on all OS.

https://dbeaver.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

You better read what platforms are supported by MySQL Workbench: http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html. The Linux world is so shattered, it's very difficult to support all flavours. And of course always my own is certainly one that should be amongst the supported platforms...

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue CentOS 6.4 :
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbscintilla.so: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_get_realized

Installed gtk2 devel libraries.
yum install gtk2-devel

Problem solved.

Thanks

Prasad

Answer (score 0):

Centos6.8, Mysql80, Mysqlworkbench8.0.17
I have encountered same problem。  tried to install other version, but not worked; tried to install gtk2, not worked as well. Finally, I thought maybe the version was not correspond, so I install gtk3, it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me were very simple steps:

1. Downloaded a previous version of MySQL Workbench just in case
2. If it still shuts down when opening the app then verify that there is no app using mysql (for example a website you are building or whatever project you are working on) Stop them all
3. Do not open the workbench and stop the mysql server in the command line:

   `sudo service mysql stop`
4. Now with mysql stopped open MySQL Workbench and open any connection
5. Once inside, MySQL should obviously not be running so now:

   `sudo service mysql start`

Voila!